# Docker Desktop: How to get current daemon mode (linux vs windows)

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop

I presume I have to use DockerCLI.exe in some manner, but I cannot for the life of me find documentation on this anywhere.

I know I can use `-SwitchDaemon` to switch modes, but I want to just get "what mode am I running right now"

Executing `& $Env:ProgramFiles\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe -h` gives very unhelpful output:

> Usage: DockerCli.exe [Command]
>
> -h, --help, -Help: Show the help information for this command

Thats it, thats all it gives, no list of commands or etc.

Is there documentation on this tool anywhere at all? When I try and search for it I just keep getting results for the docker commandline itself, not `DockerCLI.exe` for Docker Desktop, lol

Answer (score 0):

The following command achieved my desired result!

```
docker version -f '{{.Server.Os}}'
```